# Компоненты Vue3

Tags: vue3

Как мне сделать так , что бы компонент реагировал на клик как в реакте.
Тоесть у меня в родительском компоненте есть кнопки внизу и сверху они одинаковые, но нужно
синхронизировать между ними события.
Тоесть когда я жму внизу должно перерысовываться и сверху и наоборот.

```
<div>
<comp @click='a' />
<section/>
<comp @click='a'/>
<div>
```

Comment: Если использовать Composition API - через Provide/Inject можете в "верхнем" компоненте создать любую функцию и использовать ее в ЛЮБОМ компоненте/месте "одновременно"
В частности ваш @click

Comment: решил с помощью рефов